# Customise DNS per-process

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, dns, hosts-file

Is it possible (on Windows) to simulate a "per-process" hosts file? Or, is it a feature of any current web browser to be able to customise the DNS mapping?

Edit: For example, a side-by-side test lab scenario simulating a future DNS change. It would be neat to avoid having to use two separate computers!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't control the source code, it'll be tricky.  If you had control of the software you could have linked in your own DNS client library.

Personally, I'd go with virtual machines to avoid the need for two separate physical computers.